# How to auto insert current user name in Confluence?

Tags: confluence

Want to setup a template in Confluence to auto get current user name. When user creates new page with the template, it will show user's name on the page.

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done prior to asking this question?

Answer (score 0):

[Thanks this thread](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/NEED-example-of-a-user-macro-that-retrieves-the-current-username/qaq-p/517003), following [Writing User Macros Guide](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/writing-user-macros-4485.html), add below code then page will dynamically get current user name.

```
## @noparams
$action.remoteUser.name
```